# homogeneous of degree k for a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

As the book says:A function $f(x,y)$ defined in a domain D (an open set in $R^2$) is said to be homogeneous of degree $k$ if for all real $\lambda$ and $(x,y) \in D$.

$f(\lambda x,\lambda y) = \lambda ^{k}f(x,y).$

And the first-order differential equation

$M(x,y)+N(x,y)y^{'} = 0$

is said to be homogeneous if $M(x,y)$ and $N(x,y)$ are homogeneous functions of the same degree, say, $n$.

$x^{n}M(1,\frac{y}{x})+x^{n}N(1,\frac{y}{x})y^{'}=0$

Actually, I don't understand why we get here and why we need to get here? What's this purpose of defining homogeneous?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Try to convince yourself of $M(x,y) = M(x, \frac{y}{x} x) = x^n M(1, \frac{y}{x}) $.

Homogeneneity is a nice property that makes your ODEs easier to solve. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation